# Insert data from table1 to table 2 where is user id and record id

Tags: sql, insert

so I need to insert some records from table1 to table2 depending on their user_id (PVKEY) and record_id (CNKEY). Just to explain better, every user has his own unique user_id (PVKEY) and every record has his own record_id (CNKEY). One user can have couple of records but everytime when the new record is added it needs to get new record_id (CNKEY) Everytime I try to insert I get message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CNKEY', table
>   'Progress.dbo.CONTHIST'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

user_id (PVKEY): data and system type is float, primary key FALSE, allow nulls TRUE. record_id (CNKEY): data and system type is float, primary key TRUE, allow nulls FALSE, record_id (CNKEY) exists only in table2 but not in table1 and user_id (PVKEY) exists in both tables. So here is my example that I was trying to execute it without any luck:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CONTHIST (PVKEY, CONTTYPE, ASSIGNEDTO, CONTDATE, SOURCE, NOTES, CNKEY)
       SELECT Pvkey, ContactType, AssignedTo, Date, SourceCode, ContactStatus
       FROM MopUpEOC
       WHERE PVKEY in (5,7,11)
```

I hope there is some good soul who will help me, I would appreciate it a lot! :D

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear:  `CNKEY` in the matching records is `NULL`, as least on one occasion.

You have basically two options:

- Change `CNKEY` to allow `NULL` values.
- Add in some sort of default in the statement.

The latter would use `COALESCE()`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CONTHIST (PVKEY, CONTTYPE, ASSIGNEDTO, CONTDATE, SOURCE, NOTES, CNKEY)
   SELECT Pvkey, ContactType, AssignedTo, Date, SourceCode,
          COALESCE(ContactStatus, '') -- Or whatever the appropriate value would
   FROM MopUpEOC
   WHERE PVKEY in (5, 7, 11)
```

Comment: His current error is about the CNKEY field though, which he isn't providing in his statement. Insert mentions 7 fields, select only has 6.

Comment: ContactStatus it's not a problem, there is no null values. Problem is Cnkey

Comment: I'm trying to insert records from table1 to table2 depending on their id-s.  I'm getting error:

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 5 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CONTHIST'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CONTHIST'. The duplicate key value is (0). The statement has been terminated.
The problem is also with records because every one of them has his record_id which is unique for every record in table. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't passing CNKEY as a value for your insert, but you defined it as one of your columns to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CONTHIST (PVKEY, CONTTYPE, ASSIGNEDTO, CONTDATE, SOURCE, NOTES, CNKEY) -- You defined it here!
       SELECT Pvkey, ContactType, AssignedTo, Date, SourceCode, ContactStatus -- But aren't adding it here
       FROM MopUpEOC
       WHERE PVKEY in (5,7,11)
```

If this CNKEY value should be a new numeric value, you can change it in your MopUpEOC table to be an IDENTITY field, and remove it from your "INSERT INTO ..." line. That way SQL Server will automatically add an incremental numerical value to that column for every record, which will be unique.

Comment: I'm trying to insert records from table1 to table2 depending on their id-s. I'm getting error:

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 5 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CONTHIST'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CONTHIST'. The duplicate key value is (0). The statement has been terminated.
The problem is also with records because every one of them has his record_id which is unique for every record in table. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you :D

Comment: Modified my answer, hope this helps a bit.